# Verify custom Firestore fields

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

We have a tokens collection `/funTokens` where each document id is a token id and the document data contains a `name` field (the token id a field as well).

We would like to query the collection from the web (javascript) and allow access to a document only if the the request contains and match the `name` and `token` fields.

note- there are many tokens and token is not a user

Example- someone should be able to open the `funExample.com/getTokenData?token=123&name=bob` url, and in the javascript Firestore query we'll pass those parameter and validate them in the security rules.
So the query will allow access only to this document:

```
/funTokens/123: {
    token: 123,
    name: bob,
    stuf: <>
}
```

Is is possible?

Comment: Are you asking for the security rule for this need or you asking for the correct query?

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the following query: `db.doc(`funTokens/${token}`).get().then(...)` but I'm not sure how to insert the name to the query, and what suppose to be the security rule

Comment: Lets start with the query, assuming the token_id is a variable holding the token id please try the following `db.collection('funTokens').doc(token_id).get().subscribe(token => token=token)` and tell me if it succeed. For now, please use public security rules such that every query is allowed to anyone

Comment: Yes, this is working

Comment: In firebase you are quering specific doc so I think you can't insert in `get` call the `token_id` and also the `name`. The rule you need to use to confirm the query contains the token_id is: 
`match /funTokens/{token_id}{
     allow read: if request.path[4] == token_id;
    }`
If you want to change the DB there are other options to get what you want

Answer (score 1):

The query, assuming the `token_id` is a variable holding the token id, is:

```
db.collection('funTokens').doc(token_id).get().subscribe(token => token=token)
```

In firebase you are querying specific doc so I think you can't insert in `get` call the `token_id` and also the `name`.

The rule you need to use to confirm the query contains the token_id is:

```
match /funTokens/{token_id} {
        allow get: if request.path[4] == token_id;     
}
```

But as @l1b3rty mentioned in comment, this rule will by definition always be true. So you actually don't need any rule accept `allow read: true` since, if the request contain the `token_id` it allowed to read it.

If I understand correctly, your security built on the fact that only who is allowed reading the token, should know the `token_id`. So the `token_id` is kind of a secret, so you need to block the `list` operation, since `allow list` allows a user to read an entire collection or query the collection, so the user will get all token_ids. So you should use the following rule:

```
match /funTokens/{token_id} {
        allow get: true;
        allow list: false;
}
```

If you want to change the DB structure, there are other options to get what you want

Comment: @alon. Please let us know if the above answer helps you.

Comment: Your rule will by definition always be true + this is not verifying the name

Comment: @l1b3rty you are right. I just edit my answer, please take a look

Comment: Thanks! it doesn't fully solve my problem as it doesn't address the need to verify the name, but it will reduce the risk

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find a way to provide the name AND token in the request. So I would do the following:

1. Change the document structure so that the document name also contains the `name` field

   ```
   /funTokens/123_bob: {
     token: 123,
      name: bob,
      stuf: <>
   }
   ```
2. Then the rule is straightforward:

   ```
   match /funTokens/{doc_id} {
     allow get: if true;     
   }
   ```

If you cannot change the document name, then you will have to use a Cloud Function that would

1. take in input the `token id` and `name`
2. query Firestore for the document using the `token id`
3. verify that the names match
4. return the document cotent or an error depending on the previous step